# How to make navmesh agent smarter in unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, agent, navmesh

I want to create zombie enemies that chases the player, but the thing is when an enemy hit an obstacle like a wall it does not go around it, How can I make it navigate through obstacles ? Do I need to use ml-agents? is there a way to make the `navmesh` agents smarter?

I am using `navMeshAgent.SetDestination(player.position)` to chase the player.

Comment: then you havent set the obstacles correctly.  Navmesh has exactly that behavior especially for walls but moving objects, tables, bushes whatever all are easily set to be avoided

Answer (score 0):

The NavMesh is designed to take static objects like walls into account when pathfinding. If you're not seeing NavMeshAgents avoiding walls, make sure the walls are tagged as ["Navigation Static"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html) so they are considered as part of the NavMesh generation.